# how can i hide/show alert or div code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

friends. I need to hide the div when loading the page and show it when processing the button click. I tried:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    successalert.Visible = false;
    }
 protected void button1_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    successalert.Visible = true;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
<div runat="server"  class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" id="successalert" role="alert">success!</div>
```

Visible false - works correctly. But when I click the button visible true does not work.
what could be the problem?

UPDATE 1:

```
protected void button1_click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        string1...
        string2...
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO xxx () VALUES ()",con);
        sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        successalert.Visible = true;
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Response.Redirect("order.aspx");
}
<asp:button type="submit" runat="server" id="btn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-lg btn-block" Text="order" onclick="button1_click"></asp:button>
```

Comment: did you used `update panel` in your asp page?

Comment: @UdhayTitus no.

Comment: can you add your `button1` code here. It will be easy to check the issue.

Comment: @UdhayTitus updated

Comment: your code is working fine for me. `<asp:Button ID="button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="button1_click"/>`

Comment: it doesn't work for me. does not show alert when I click on the button

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd code snip can't work.

Remember, the code behind NEVER interacts with the user! It ONLY can modify the web page.

So, this is what occurs:

You have this setup:
[image]

NOTE VERY careful here - the web page is ON CLIENT computer - it is NOT existing at all on the web server side.

You do not have this:
[image]

And, you do not have this either:

[image]

Ok, You click the button. Now the so called round trip starts.

[image]

Your web page is sent up to the server. You now have this:
[image]

So NOW your page is sitting on the server. This is WHY I stated your code behind does NOT interact with the user, but ONLY the web page, and ONLY for that short time the page is up on the server.

NOW your code behind starts running. Your code behind can modify controls (even visible), but the page is NOT interacting with the user - ONLY code can MODIFY the web page.

So, your code starts running;

```
Step 1: con.Open(); SqlDataAdapter sda = new ....... 
Step 2: sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Step 3: con.Close();
Step 4: successalert.Visible = true;
```

now look at the last picture - our web page is STILL up on the server. The user does not see anything that your code is doing behind.

and our first 4 steps? Hey, we doing quite good.

But then we have this:

```
Step 5: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

All that is going to do is HALT the code - make it sleep, and make the user wait longer - the web page code behind is STILL up on the server.

Only AFTER ALL your code is run, then what happens? The web page travels back down to the browser like this:

[image]

so only after the sleep, THEN the code is done, and the web page starts it trip back down to the client, and any changes your code made to the web page will now render.

Again, your code changes the web page - it does NOT interact with the user. So only AFTER that code is 100% done, then and only then can the web page start and make it trip back down to the browser.

```
 Step: 6 - Response.Redirect - next page!!
```

Oh??? Ok, but we not even let the page travel back down client side, and now we are deciding to jump to another page - the user will thus NEVER see any results of your code that modified the page. Remember, the user does NOT see code behind changes until such time the WHOLE page zooms back down to client side. So your code behind can ONLY make changes to the page - not that the user sees such changes AS THEY are being made. They can only see the page AFTER all code is done, exits and then the page travels back down to client side. Then the page renders in browser, and your JavaScript or anything else on that page client side is done - and it displays.

So with your redirect, you never let the page travel back down, but in fact are now jumping to a new page.

Your code behind can not halt, or wait - since all that does is keep the page stuck up on the server side while that code makes changes to the web page. But as you make changes, the users can't see that - they will only see changes AFTER the fact that the page travels back down the client side.

I took some time to explain the above, since without this simple concept, then web development will forever be a mystery, and you wonder why the user never sees your visible code - but then again we never let the page travel back down. So if you just have a button on the form, and set something visible = true (or false), then that control will be "set" by the code behind, but until such time the page travels back down to the client side browser and is displayed? Then they can't see the effects of those changes (like visible = true).

of course what means is that if you want to display a message? you have to display it on the page your jumping to!!!

Or, what you must do is have the button in the browser run some code client side BEFORE the post-back!!!

So, You would have to have some browser code run BEFORE the web page makes that trip up to the browser. Or you I suppose you could show the div - but it would need a "ok" button that when clicked on would jump to your next page in question.

Or as noted, you could write some js, and display the div BEFORE the button is clicked.

Say like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="showmydiv();return true;"  
        runat="server" Text="Button" Width="90px" />

<div runat="server" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" 
   id="successalert" role="alert" ClientIDMode=Static
    Style="Display:none">success!</div>

    <script>
        function showmydiv() {
            $('#successalert').Show();
       }
    </script>
```

So now, we display the div BEFORE the post back (OnClientClick="myjavafunction();return true" does this.

Now the div will display (because the code is running client/browser side.

Now your server side button code will run. It will "halt" for 3 seconds but our current page (browser side) is still waiting - so the web page client side is still there - and it will be showing that div. Then after that 3 seconds, your code will continue to the next line (Reponse.Redirect("my next page").

So in effect, you have the page with code behind finish for the user to see the changes you made, or simply reverse this, display the div, then code behind runs - while it is running the local JavaScript code will have run, and will show/display the div. Also note that I used Style="display:none". You can NOT USE visible = false, since any control set that way NEVER travels down in the browser, and such controls are never rendered - so the control (div) would not even exist if we set visible = false. But with style="display:none" then the control exists browser side - but not displayed.

I also used jQuery syntax to get/grab and hide the div. I suppose if you not using jQuery then you have to write that not using jQuery - but i recommend you use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in event load of page, check for : **IsPostBack**

```
void Page_Load(...)
{
...
if(Page.IsPostBack)
return;
successalert.Visible=false;
...
}
```